# To search Rich Text Area field

Tags: soql, sosl

Custom field `Cont__c`, data type is Rich Text Area,

but in the custom Visualforce Searchpage can't to search and error information:

> System.QueryException: field '`Cont__c`' can not be filtered in query
>   call.

I want to know Rich Text Area or Long Text Area fidles whether can to search? As I do not want to go to the ideaxchange for that https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ksTKAAY

Comment: You've already answered your own question...you can't do it. What are you looking for from us?

Comment: If there is any workaround

Comment: @cloudlover - You have already answered that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can not use text area or rich text area in where clause of soql query, salesforce doesn't allow it.

But we can use alternate solution

```
for( object_c ob : [SELECT id, Cont__c name FROM object_c] ) {
    if(ob.Cont__c.contains('string to be filtered')) {

    }
}
```